# How to merge pdf files with PDFReactor 5.1

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-reactor

I am working with an established application where PDFReactor 5.1 is in use. The company will not upgrade it for a while (maybe another 1-2 years).

I was tasked with building functionality to merge pdf files (a appending all pdfs will do) from a C# based web application.

Reading though the old docs of this tool (which are from 2012) I have found they propose this type of usage:

> To merge multiple PDFs use the methods setMergeURLs or
> setMergeByteArrays
>
> ```
> String[] urls = {"http://www.myserver.com/overlaid1.pdf", "http://www.myserver.com/overlaid2.pdf"};
> pdfReactor.setMergeURLs(urls);
> pdfReactor.setMergeMode(PDFreactor.MERGE_MODE_APPEND);
> ```

However, the documentation does not specify what method to call to render the merged pdf and `setMergeURLs` does not return a value (`public void SetMergeURLs(string[] urls)`)

I can see there are 3 render methods, when I explore the client DLL, but all of them require some input (presumably in addition to the pdf you set with `setMergeURLs`):

- `public byte[] RenderDocumentFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray)`
- `public byte[] RenderDocumentFromContent(string content)`
- `byte[] RenderDocumentFromURL(string URL)`

I tried using these 3 render methods but they only result on an empty array with the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

it seems PDF reactor is trying to do a conversion from XML to pdf instead of the merge...

what am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with RealObjects's Support (pdf reactor's creator) and this is their answer:

> In general PDFreactor is not intended to just merge existing PDFs. You
> can only merge one or more existing PDFs to an actual HTML to PDF
> conversion. See also our [FAQ](https://support.realobjects.com/en/support/solutions/articles/7000018262-can-i-merge-a-set-of-existing-pdfs-without-converting-an-additional-html-).

This FAQ looks like intended for the current version only, so it does not really help with the usage of version 5.1 (as I require).

I kept trying a little more until I finally got it to merge. This is the main part of it:

```
var pdfReactor = new PDFreactor();
pdfReactor.SetLicenseKey(myLicenseKey);
pdfReactor.SetMergeMode(PDFreactor.MERGE_MODE_PREPEND); // prepend because it seems to reference the doc to be generated by RenderDocumentFromContent
pdfReactor.SetMergeByteArrays(
    new[]
    {
        File.ReadAllBytes("c:/pdfs/first.pdf"),
        File.ReadAllBytes("c:/pdfs/second.pdf")
    });

var merged = pdfReactor.RenderDocumentFromContent("<html></html>");

File.WriteAllBytes($@"C:\pdfs\merged.pdf", merged);
```

The `merged.pdf` file contains the other two files however it is started with a blank page (due to the `<html></html>` I had it use on the `RenderDocumentFromContent` call to make it not produce errors).

That is as far as this exercise will go for me, I will leave it at that and consider another tool to do pdf merging, as I wouldn't want this blank page around.